# Is there a way to produce definite integrals of composite functions with Sympy's integrate() function?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm creating a calculator that can calculate definite integrals. I use the Sympy integrate() function to create definite integrals. But I can't seem to get Sympy to do definite integrals of composite functions, like sin(cos(x)).

Here's my code that I tried:

```
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify
from sympy import *
import sympy as sp
from math import *
import math


def d_integrate():
    def g(x):
        final = eval(f)
        return final
    f = input("Enter the function you want to integrate: ")
    if ("^" in f):
        f = f.replace("^", "**")

# the following part deals with special bounds

    lbound = input("\nEnter the lower bound: ")
    if ("pi" in lbound):
        lbound = lbound.replace("pi", str(math.pi))
        lbound = eval(lbound)
        lbound = float(lbound)
    elif ("e" in lbound):
        lbound = lbound.replace("e", str(math.e))
        lbound = eval(lbound)
        lbound = float(lbound)
    else:
        lbound = float(lbound)
    rbound = input("Enter the upper bound: ")
    if ("pi" in rbound):
        rbound = rbound.replace("pi", str(math.pi))
        rbound = eval(rbound)
        rbound = float(rbound)
    elif ("e" in rbound):
        rbound = rbound.replace("e", str(math.e))
        rbound = eval(rbound)
        rbound = float(rbound)
    else:
        rbound = float(rbound)
    if (("1/x" in f or f == "x^-1") and (lbound <= 0 or lbound <= lbound + 1)):
        return("\nDiverging integral. Cannot solve.")
    x = sp.Symbol("x")
    if str(integrate(f, (x, lbound, rbound))) == "nan":
        return "\nIntegral does not converge. Cannot Solve."
    else:
        print("\nCalculated integral of", f, "from", lbound, "to", rbound, ". Final area is", integrate(f, (x, lbound, rbound)))
```

When I enter sin(cos(x)) as f (the function we want to integrate), and lower/upper bounds of, say 0 and pi, it returns this:

```
Calculated integral of sin(cos(x)) from 0.0 to 3.141592653589793 . Final area is Integral(sin(cos(x)), (x, 0.0, 3.14159265358979))
```

instead of the desire number. It isn't an error, per se, but no matter what I try it's just not calculating the definite integral. How can I integrate this? Or if Sympy is incapable of this, are there other modules that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an analytical result cannot be obtained, SymPy returns an unevaluated Integral class. Either of the two can be evaluated numerically with the `evalf()` method. Here, for example, I compute the integral from 0 to pi/2 (so there is a non-zero result to show) and use the alias `n` with a requested precision of 5 digits:

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> Integral(sin(cos(x)),(x,0,pi/2)).n(5)
0.89324
```

Notice that I use `sympy.core.numbers.pi` instead of `math.pi`.

Comment: hi @smichr, thanks for the tip! I think my problem is solved completely. Again, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Sympy is great at analytical operations... when the solution exists!

`sin(cos(x))` has no analytical primitive, so you can either keep the integral to get an exact result or try finding a numeric approximation.

Sympy is kind enough to give you the best exact result it can find, so here `Integral(sin(cos(x)), (x, 0.0, 3.14159265358979))`.

If you want a numeric approximation, just `evalf` it:

```
print(integrate(sympify(sin(cos(x))), (x, 0, pi)).evalf())
```

gives:

```
0.e-104
```

Which is a close approximation of the true `0` value that you can mathematically deduce by symmetry of the functions `cos` and `sin`.